# Redux, Reselect and ImmutableJS causing unnecessary renders on child components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

Based on all the Redux and Reselect docs I have just read and re-read the below selector should only do the `thing.toJS()` processing if the Immutable Map that `getThing()` returns is not equal to the previous one.

```js
...

// Selector

import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

const getThing = (state, thingId) => {
    return state.entities.getIn(['things', thingId])
}

const makeThingSelector = () => {
    return createSelector(
        [getThing],
        (thing) => {
            return thing.toJS()
        }
    )
}

export default makeThingSelector

...

// Container

const makeMapStateToProps = () => {
    return (state, ownProps) => {
        const { thingId } = ownProps
        const things = select.makeThingsSelector()(state, thingId)

        return {
            hasNoThings: things.length === 0,
            things
        }
    }
}

const Container = connect(
    makeMapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Component)
...
```

This holds true unless I have a child 'smart' component. In this case, when the parent triggers a render, the selector called in the child component's container always processes the value regardless of whether the result is new or not.

I have been trying to encapsulate the ImmutableJS API inside my selectors but this means to avoid a re render on these nested components every time their parents update I have to do a deep equality check in the `shouldComponentUpdate` function. This is expensive and doesn't seem like a decent solution.

The app state is normalised so the updated part of the state tree is not a hierarchical parent to the part of the state that the child component is dependent on.

Am I missing something key here?

Comment: The code you posted looks correct and should behave as expected. Please, provide the code which use these selector and connects your `Components` to `store`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On every `store` update `react-redux` performs following steps (putting all internal complexities aside):

1. Calls `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`.
2. Shallowly comparing resulted `props`
3. Re-renders `Component` In case new `props` differs from previous one.

This way `mapStateToProps` will be called on every `store` update by-design. So will following line of code:

```
...
const things = select.makeThingsSelector()(state, visitId)
...
```

As you can see new `reselect` selector will be created every time effectively preventing any memoization (there are no global state in `reselect`, memoization happens per selector).

What you have to do is change your code so that one and the same selector will be used on every invocation of `mapStateToProps`:

```
const thingSelector = select.makeThingsSelector();

...

const makeMapStateToProps = () => {
    return (state, ownProps) => {
        const { visitId } = ownProps
        const things = thingSelector(state, visitId)

        return {
            hasNoThings: things.length === 0,
            things
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Also I don't see any reason to use factory-style `makeThingsSelector` and `makeMapStateToProps`. Why not just go with something like:

```
...

// Selector

export default createSelector(
  [getThing],
  (thing) => thing.toJS()
);

...

// Container

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const { visitId } = ownProps
  const things = select.thingsSelector(state, visitId)
  return {
    hasNoThings: things.length === 0,
    things
  }
}

const Container = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Component)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the redux state in this application uses the `ImmutableJS` data structure, `Reselect` may not be necessary.

Firstly, `ImmutableJS` manipulates only the slice of the data structure affected by a change operation and therefore all changes to the larger state may not affect the slice being passed to the container.

Secondly, the redux connect function returns a pure container by default and upon encountering same slice will not re-render. However, the `mapStateToProps` will be invoked since the whole state and possibly the ownProps have changed.

For finer control, the rendering of same container can be linked directly to changes to a particular slice of the state and `ownProps` by adding `areStatesEqual` and `areOwnPropsEqual` predicate properties to the fourth parameter of the connect function (better known as the `options` object).

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ entities }, { thingId }) => {
    const things = entities.getIn(['things', thingId]).toJS();
    return {
        hasNoThings: things.length === 0,
        things
   };
};

const Container = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
    undefined, {
        areOwnPropsEqual: (np, pp) => np.thingId === pp.thingId,
        areStatesEqual: (ns, ps) => ns.entities.get(‘things’).equals(
            ps.entities.get(‘things’)
        )
    }
)(Component);
```

If both of these predicates are true, not only would the container and its children not re-render, the `mapStateToProps` would not even be invoked!